# Difficult Homogeneous Differential Equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3xy+4y^2}}{x+2y}$$

I tried to solve it by putting $t=x+2y$ but that lead to a very complicated integral. The hint given is that equation is reducible to homogeneous form.

Comment: hint : $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sqrt{1+3\frac{y}{x}+4\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}}{1+2\frac{y}{x}}$

Comment: It leads to a difficult integral. Is there another way.

Comment: Look at the (beginning of) answer I wrote. Is it the difficult integral you are talking about ?

Comment: Do you have the answer sheet with you?

Comment: You should provide more information on the equation, such as textbook, model, etc. If you are just curious to changing something or randomly picking an differential equation and ask how to (analytically) solve it, you are in wrong direction of learning

Answer (score 5):

I suppose a typo and that the problem is $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\color{red}{4}xy+4y^2}}{x+2y}$$ Doing the same steps as in NAC's answer, we get $$\frac{dx}x=\frac {du}{1-u}$$ taht is to say

$$\log(x)+C=-\log(1-u)$$

Comment: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\color{red}{4}xy+4y^2}}{x+2y}$$ Isn't the RHS just $1$ for $x+2y>0$?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question; you cannot assume a typo and solve a slightly different but easier equation, that's not how it works.

Comment: @projectilemotion. For sure ! Bust may be, this is what they want. Assuming that the problem is an assignment, it is, from far, extremely difficult, not to say impossible to solve.

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer :**

Reformulate it as $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sqrt{1+3\frac{y}{x}+4\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}}{1+2\frac{y}{x}}$$

The you have $dy/dx = f(y/x)$.

Let $u(x) = \frac{y(x)}{x}$. Then $xu = y$. Then $dy = xdu + udx$. Then $dy/dx = xdu/dx + u$. Then you have
$$x\frac{du}{dx}+u = f(u)\quad \text{where} \quad f(u) = \frac{\sqrt{1+3u+4u^2}}{1+2u}$$
Then $x\frac{du}{dx} = f(u)-u$. Then
$$\int \frac{du}{f(u)-u} = \int\frac{dx}{x}$$
i.e.
$$\int \frac{1+2u}{\sqrt{4u^2+3u+1}-u-2u^2} = \int\frac{dx}{x}$$
So this must be solved (to get further from here). It'd give you $u(x)$ as a function of $x$ and from there you get $y(x)$ using $y(x)=x u(x)$. Here's a beginning :

$$\frac{1+2u}{\sqrt{4u^2+3u+1}-(u+2u^2)} = \frac{(1+2u)(\sqrt{4u^2+3u+1}+u+2u^2)}{4u^2+3u+1-(u+2u^2)^2}
\\ = -\frac{(1+2u)(\sqrt{4u^2+3u+1}+u+2u^2)}{4u^4 + 4u^3 - 3u^2 - 3u -1}
\\ = -\frac{(\sqrt{4u^2+3u+1}+u+2u^2)}{2u^3 + 2u^2 - 2u - \frac{u+1}{2u+1}}
\\ = \text{ugly...}$$

**Then :** either *goto* Claude Leibovici's highly plausible answer or please post yours if you know how to solve this.

Comment: The point is how to solve integral in u.

Comment: I'm thinking about it.

Comment: I am skeptical about a closed form of this integral.

Comment: Did you get $ugly=something$ ?

Comment: anyone tried to feed Wolfram with the initial problem ?

Comment: ugly = nothing that seems digestible

Comment: Wolfram's answer to $dy/dx = sqrt(x^2+3xy+4y^2)/(x+2y)$ : "Standard computation time exceeded...".

Comment: I guess a typo : $3$ should be $4$ !!

Comment: This is only a partial answer with the final (and arguably the most important) step missing; the solution

Comment: @nluigi Yes this is a partial answer.

Answer (score 1):

The integral that Noé AC derived is expressible in terms of elementary functions although it is highly messy. Integration of any rational function $R(u,\sqrt{P_2(u)})$, where $P_2$ is a quadratic, can be reduced to the integration of a rational function.

The first step is the reduction to a rational function of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$. In order to do this we take the integral
$$
\int \frac{1+2u}{\sqrt{4 u^2 + 3 u + 1} - u - 2u^2} du
$$
and make the trig substitution $ 2 u + \frac34 = \frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}\tan\theta$. This leads to an integrand that is a rational function of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$. I got something like
$$
\int \frac{2\sqrt{7}\left(\cos\theta + \sqrt{7} \sin\theta\right)}{3 \cos^3\theta + 8 \sqrt{7} \cos^2\theta + 2 \sqrt{7} \sin\theta \cos^2\theta - 7 \sin^2\theta \cos\theta} d\theta
$$
The integral of any rational function of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ can be converted to the integral of a rational function of $t$ through the change of variables $ t = \tan(\frac{\theta}{2});d\theta =  \frac{2dt}{1+t^2}; \sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}; \cos\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$. This leads to the integration of a rational function of $t$. I get that the resulting integral is
$$
\int -\frac{16 \left(t^2+1\right)\left(t^2-2 \sqrt{7} t-1\right)}{\left(t^2-1\right)
   \left(\left(8 \sqrt{7}-3\right) t^4+4 \sqrt{7} t^3+34 t^2-4 \sqrt{7} t-8
   \sqrt{7}-3\right)}dt
$$
This integral is in principle doable with partial fractions, although the roots of the quartic don't seem to be anything nice. I stopped here because it did not seem pointful to me to do the partial fractions with numerical approximations for the roots.

Although this is ultimately expressible in terms of elementary functions I strongly suspect that there was a typo in this problem.